# How to use promise chaining in my coding in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
exports.updateMyData = function (data) {
    var resultPromise = Q.defer();
    var errorResponse = function (err) {
        resultPromise.reject(err);
    };
    findById(data.id).then(function (mydata) {
        if (!mydata) {
            errorResponse("No item found to update");
        }
        mydata.updateAttributes(data).then(function (mydata) {
            resultPromise.resolve(mydata)
        }, errorResponse)
    }, errorResponse);
    return resultPromise.promise;
};
```

Above coding is working fine but I want to use promise chaining for above coding. Please help me how to use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
exports.updateMyData = function (data) {
    return findById(data.id).then(function (mydata) {
        if (!mydata) {
            throw new Error("No item found to update");
        }
        return mydata.updateAttributes(data);
    });
};
```

or chained like this:

```
exports.updateMyData = function (data) {
    return findById(data.id).then(function (mydata) {
        if (!mydata) {
            throw new Error("No item found to update");
        }
        return mydata;
    }).then(function(data) {
        return mydata.updateAttributes(data);
    });
};
```

Note how both these options return the internal promises rather than creating a new promise.  Also, a `throw` within a `.then()` handler will reject that promise automatically.

Creating a new promise like your original code was doing when you can just return the one you already have is considered a [promise anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns) and should be avoided.

Comment: @ppshein - On what line of code does that error occur?  Are you passing `data` as an argument when you call the exported function?

Comment: sorry, actual error is `mydata is not defined`. error showing `return mydata.updateAttributes(data);` that line.

Comment: @ppshein - That's your code - I just copied from your question.  You'd have to tell us what `mydata` is supposed to be.

Comment: @ppshein - Do you perhaps mean it to be `data.updateAttributes(mydata)`?